# Unable to extract MKV attachments with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract attachments from an MKV file by following the documentation at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

Direct quote from documentation:

```
To extract all attachments to files determined by the filename tag:  
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" INPUT
```

The command I'm running on my computer is this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -dump_attachment:t "" INPUT
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x7f981182ae00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'INPUT'
INPUT: Invalid argument
```

How can I extract attachments from my test.mkv file?  Am I misunderstanding what `INPUT` is supposed to be?

I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" test.mkv
```

and FFmpeg prompts me with this:

```
File 'test.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N].
```

Entering `y` replaces test.mkv with a 0 byte file, and no attachments are extracted.

---

**Additional Information:**

I installed ffmpeg via [brew](https://brew.sh/) using the following command:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype --with-libass --with-tools
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation was wrong. This bug [has been fixed now](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/2299#no3). The examples were missing an `-i` flag to properly designate the input file:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i test.mkv
```

This worked for me in FFmpeg 1.1.2 and above. Note that FFmpeg will still complain about no output file being specified. Don't worry about this though: The attachments will still be extracted.

---

You can also extract attachments from MKV files with [MKVToolNix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/).  This set of programs can be [easily downloaded](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html) from the website for all operating systems, or in OS X installed with `brew install mkvtoolnix`.

Look at the IDs of your attachments:

```
mkvmerge -i <mkv-file>
```

Then extract them:

```
mkvextract attachments <mkv-file> <attachment-id>:<file-name>
```

See the [`mkvextract` documentation](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html#mkvextract.description.attachments). If the `<file-name>` is empty, a name will be chosen automatically. You can also specify multiple pairs of `<attachment-id>:<file-name>`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer, if you add `-t 0 -f null null` to the end of the command, it will stop giving you errors.

```sh
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i test.mkv -t 0 -f null null
```

Also, if you're running the command on PowerShell, you need to place the empty string inside quotes, like this:

```sh
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t '""' -i test.mkv -t 0 -f null null
```